# Tracking the length of time an object exists in a given state

Tags: c#, oop, session

I'm designing an application that will create multiple `Session` objects, which
can exist in a two states: 'active' and 'inactive'. Only a single `Session`
object can be in the 'active' state at any one time and any one `Session` object can change between 'active' and 'inactive' any number of times during its lifetime. A `Session` object also has a `DurationActive` property of type `TimeSpan` that represents the total time that the `Session` was in the 'active' state.

Any suggestions on how I could implement this?

Comment: _"solving this problem"_ What _problem_?

Comment: You know you're kind reinventing the wheel, right?

Comment: Let's see what you got - at the moment it looks like a "please write this code for me" question

Comment: @Renan No I don't - can you elaborate

Comment: @BrokenGlass I do have one or two ideas of my own, which I'll post.

Comment: I'm quite sure there are classes for that. But then again - if you do reinvent the wheel, at least you have a better understanding of wheels in general than the average Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chris' suggestion for using the Mediator pattern, I've come with what I believe is a better solution.

In order to control access, the following classes would exist inside their own Assembly:

```
namespace Sessions
{

    public interface ISession
    {
        bool IsActive { get; }
        TimeSpan DurationActive { get; }
    }

    internal class Session : ISession
    {
        private Stopwatch _stopwatch;
        private bool _isChargeable;

        public bool IsActive
        {
            get { return _stopwatch.IsRunning; }
        }

        public TimeSpan DurationActive
        {
            get { return _stopwatch.Elapsed;  }
        }

        internal Session()
        {
            _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        }

        internal void Activate()   
        {
            _stopwatch.Start();
        }

        internal void Deactivate()
        {
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
    }

    public sealed class SessionMediator
    {

        private static readonly SessionMediator _instance = new SessionMediator();

        public static ISession CreateSession()
        {
            return _instance.createSession();
        }

        public static void ActivateSession(ISession session)
        {
            _instance.activateSession((Session)session);
        }

        private Session _currentSession = null;

        private SessionMediator() { }

        private ISession createSession()
        {
            return new Session();
        }

        private void activateSession(Session session)
        {
            // Deactivate the current session
            if (_currentSession != null)
                _currentSession.Deactivate();

            // Make the given session the current session
            _currentSession = session;

            // Activate the new current session
            if (_currentSession != null)
                _currentSession.Activate();
        }

    }

}
```

And my test program, in a separate Assembly:

```
namespace TestSessionProgram
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            ISession session1 = SessionMediator.CreateSession();
            ISession session2 = SessionMediator.CreateSession();
            ISession session3 = SessionMediator.CreateSession();

            SessionMediator.ActiveSession(session1)
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Debug.Assert(session1.DurationActive == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            SessionMediator.ActiveSession(session2)
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Debug.Assert(session2.DurationActive == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            SessionMediator.ActiveSession(session1)
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Debug.Assert(session1.DurationActive == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The effect you are implementing with a `Timer` already exists within the .Net framework as [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17810911/1894317) above.

Answer (score 5):

To control the Active/inactive state of other session objects have a look into the Mediator Pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

This should allow you to keep the Session objects decoupled, and also abstract the interaction away from your main code

Answer (score 4):

The solution depends on whether you want *Active* to be achieved by setting a property, or by calling a method.

I'll only cover the latter option, as, in my opinion, it/s cleaner to code (and hence, maintain).

You will need A `MakeActive()` method (or similar), and a `MakeInactive()` method.

`MakeActive()` will:

1. Check that all other Sessions are inactive (although this could - perhaps should - be handled at a higher level).
2. Start a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) object, which would be a private member of the class.  When the Stopwatch is instanciated will depend on what exactly you want to time: just the last activation, or the total activation in the Session's life.
3. Make the Session active.

`MakeInactive()` will:

1. Make the seeion inactive
2. Stop the `Stopwatch` object.

Then implementing `TimeActive` is simply a case of getting the `Stopwatch`'s `Elapsed` property, perhaps with guards so it is only valid when the session is Inactive.

Comment: +1 for Stopwatch. Although I don't think it's the Session object's job to ensure that all other Session objects are inactive. I would remove your step 1 in `MakeActive`. That's the job of the calling application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a static `DateTime` property `LastChange`. In property `State` (or in function `SetActive`, or whatever) add to `DurationActive` the difference between `DateTime.Now` and `LastChange`. Also update `LastChange` to `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: `DateTime.Now - startTime` breaks down when DST changes.  It's not designed for measuring durations.  `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` is a better alternative.